# Should an arrow connect a enumeration data type to a class in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, enumeration, class-diagram

In our UML class diagram, we have days of the week as an enumeration. We have a class that has a parameter -day: DaysOfTheWeek. However we are uncertain whether we should connect the enumeration to the class with an arrow and if so what arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining the parameter to be of type DaysOfTheWeek, you have created a dependency of that class on DaysOfTheWeek. You can visualize this dependency by drawing a dependency relationship (a dashed arrow with an open arrowhead) from the class to DaysOfTheWeek, but it is redundant, because the dependency is already in the model.

It is up to you to decide whether or not to do this. I would advise to make a decision in your design team to either always draw these dependency arrows between classes and data types or never.

Comment: I provided pretty similar answer to pretty similar question in the past. One additional remark though: in most CASE tools there is a benefit of explicitly creating the dependency, that is proper traceability. Having said that, if the team decision is to not show the explicit dependency, it's usually possible to remove the dependency from the diagram once it is created, keeping it at the model level.

Comment: Thanks for the response I appreciate it! What would you recommend to do if the enumeration is used by multiple classes? Again thank you for your time :)

Comment: I would not draw the dependency relationships, to avoid cluttering.

Comment: @CaitlynCodr, if you are satisfied with the answer, please click the checkmark to accept it. This would give me some credit points.